# How i can get the max value of a sum of multiple columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

My table

```
Name  column1 column2 column3
Julio 24      25      35
Jaime 30      40      35
```

This is my query

```
Select a.name, max(column1+column2+column3) from table group by name
```

How i can get the max value of a sum of multiple columns?

Comment: sqlserver, oracle, mysql, .. ?

Answer (score 3):

I executed this query in SQL Server 2014. 
Hope this will help you

```
select name, max(column1+column2+column3) as MaxSum from table
group by name
having max(column1+column2+column3)= (select max(column1+column2+column3) from table)
```

Answer (score 2):

With the query you have

```
select a.name, max(column1+column2+column3) from table group by name
```

the result would be all the names and their sum of columns with the assumption that each name will have one corresponding row.

If you need the name corresponding to the max of the summation, use

```
select name, column1+column2+column3 as sum
from table t
join (select max(column1+column2+column3) as maxsum from table) t1
on t.column1+column2+column3 = t1.maxsum
```

To just get the max sum use

```
select max(column1+column2+column3) as maxsum from table
```

Comment: *remark:* joining with maxsum may yield multiple rows when equal.

Comment: yes..and what is often forgotten at first in application logic

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this with `order by` and `fetch first 1 row only` (in Oracle 12+):

```
Select a.name,
       sum(coalesce(column1, 0) + coalesce(column2, 0) + coalesce(column3, 0)) as s
from table
group by a.name
order by sum(coalesce(column1, 0) + coalesce(column2, 0) + coalesce(column3, 0))  desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

In earlier versions, use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (Select a.name,
             sum(coalesce(column1, 0) + coalesce(column2, 0) + coalesce(column3, 0)) as s
      from table
      group by a.name
      order by sum(coalesce(column1, 0) + coalesce(column2, 0) + coalesce(column3, 0))  desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```